# Problem with localhost:8080 using WMS and WFS services

Tags: wms, wfs, localhost

I am facing a problem and I believe that my localhost port may be the main issue.

First of all, I am trying to connect my QGIS with these links of WMS 
 (http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&) and WFS (http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&acceptversions=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities&) services.

However, at my PC the connection fails, referring me that the connection is refused.

I think that the GeoServer service which I have installed two day ago, might be the main problem. I connected it with localhost:8080, reserving this port close. As a result, the links of the services can't connect.

I tried to uninstall GeoServer, reinstalling it using a different port (1234), but the problem wasn't resolved. I think that the 8080 port is still reserved from the first installation.

Also, I have requested the services in another PC, using QGIS, and the services worked fine. 
Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do the requests work in a browser, but not in QGIS, or not at all?

Comment: No, the requests don't work neither in a browser. However, the requests work fine in a different PC using QGIS software.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.